# 自分自身に対して多対多を持つモデルのDBへ外部キー制約を追加する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails

以下のように自分自身に対して多対多の関係を持つモデルを使っています。

#### models/user.rb

```
has_many :friendships
has_many :friends, through: :friendships
```

#### models/friendship.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :friend, class_name: "User"
```

この`Friendship`を作成する時に`create_table`で`foreign_key: true`の制約をつけると当然ですがエラーになってしまいます。

```
create_table :friendships do |t|
  t.references :user, foreign_key: true
  t.references :friend
end
```

ですので、以上のように制限無しで作成してしまっているのですが

この`friendships`の`friend_id`カラムに外部キー制約を追加するにはどのようにすればよいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t.references :friend, foreign_key: { to_table: :users }
```

とすると、  `create_table` の中で実行できるような気がします。

Answer (score 0):

質問を書いた後に`add_foreign_key`のドキュメントを見たら書いてました…。

```
create_table :friendships do |t|
  t.references :user, foreign_key: true
  t.references :friend
end
add_foreign_key :friendships, :users, column: :friends_id
```

で`friend_id`カラムにも外部キー制約を行えました。